# Pros/Cons Of using LINQ in (Design patterns, App N-Tier architecture)

Tags: linq, design-patterns, architecture

for those who developed/Designed large application using LINQ2SQL tech

What is the Pros/Cons (whats the limitations and whats the things i must be a ware off) when using LINQ in such a thing

Thank you.

Comment: Where do you intend to use LINQ in your design? Are you referring to something like LINQ2SQL or just usage of standard query operators?

Comment: IN LINQ2SQL, a 3 tiers pattern, as a core library for (CRUD)

Answer (score 1):

You want to keep clean separation of concerns - so no data access in the business logic, etc.

Typically I'd define that boundary using an interface, and you can't have any data access specific stuff in here either (otherwise you're dragging those dependencies into anything that deals with the interface.

Within a data access implelentation you can do what you want, at this point it'd be a straight shoot-out between your favorite database access technologies; and I'd imagine there's no shortage of comparions out there online (sorry I don't have that in my head to give you).

I haven't used LinQ2Sql myself, but I know a few people who love it; the phrase "Lin2SQL F##king ROCKS man" comes to mind (from one of my more vocal friends).

Comment: thats right, i'm using the same concepts you talking about, soon i'll post the pattern i created with linq ( 3 tiers separated between business objects, data access layer and data service) in order to discuss, but what i noticed through my experience during the implementation that linq rocks for small - semi large app, but it got sucks in large app and come more complex to deal and overcome every case pop-up in the way, it needs a well LINQ-educated developer to deal with (regardless performance and time wasting), hope to hear from ppl already did that!